# Slurm parallel "steps": 25 independent runs, using 1 cpu each, at most 5 simultaneously

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

I was previously using HTCondor as a cluster scheduler. Now even after reading Slurm documentation, I have no idea how to parallelize...

What I want to achieve is called --I think-- "embarrassingly parallel": running multiple independent instances of a program (with different inputs).

What I want: request 5 CPUs, possibly on distinct nodes; each CPUs runs the monothreaded program with its specific input. As soon as one CPU is freed, start on the next input in the queue.

Using a batch script, I tried two approaches (please help me understand their difference):

1. [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html)
2. [packed jobs](https://support.ceci-hpc.be/doc/_contents/QuickStart/SubmittingJobs/SlurmTutorial.html#packed-jobs-example)

If life was simple, I would assume sufficient to combine the following sbatch options:

`--ntasks=5`: to have at most 5 runs simultaneously?

`--cpus-per-task=1`: each run uses one CPU (it should be the default value)

###### 1. **job array** option

I try `--array=0-24%5`, even if `%5` appears redundant with `--ntasks=5`, or is it different?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --job-name=myprogram
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3000 # MB
#SBATCH --output=slurmed/myprogram_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=slurmed/myprogram_%a.err
#SBATCH --ntasks=5
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=0-24%5

input_files=(myinput*.txt)

srun ./myprogram "${input_files[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"
```

However, it persists in allocating several CPUs to each "SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"!!!

I also tried without specifying `--ntasks` at all, same problem.

###### 2. Packed jobs (using ampersand spawning)

(Sorry, but why would a cluster scheduler even let you manually parallelize using shell syntax?)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --job-name=myprogram
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3000 # MB
#SBATCH --output=slurmed/myprogram_%J_%t.out
#SBATCH --error=slurmed/myprogram_%J_%t.err
#SBATCH --ntasks=5
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1

for inputfile in myinput*.txt; do
    srun --exclusive ./myprogram "$input_file" &
done
wait
```

However if I watch `htop` on the machine it is running, I see that the first job is running 5 times, and that the sbatch command is also using one extra CPU!

Should I remove the `--exclusive`?

---

P.S: There is a useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577947/4614641), but as I said my array command uses multiple CPUs per array unit, instead of one.

P.P.S: Additionally, the Slurm terminology is also extremely confusing:

- a *job*: something submitted using sbatch and/or srun?
- a *job step*: each time an executable is called inside the batch script? Despite being called a "step", it can occur in parallel
- a *task*: I don't see the difference with a *job step*, but the option descriptions imply that it is different (someone also [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39186698/4614641)).

Answer (score 1):

So actually, my problem was answered here: [NumCPUs shows 2 when --cpus-per-task=1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70795851/4614641). Due to hyperthreading, a physical cores of 2 threads is allocated for each job. So requesting 1 CPU per task will anyway be using 2 CPUs in slurm reports. However these 2 threads are concurrent, so running a parallelized command on it will not provide acceleration. If I want true parallelization, I have to request 4, 6, 8 or more CPUs

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the last part? You mean they have to be an even number since since each cpu has 2 threads?

Comment: No, well it's true but it's not my point; if you ask `--cpus-per-task=2`, you are asking for 2 threads and there is no physical parallelization (it's just threading). To take advantage of multiple **physical CPUs** for real, you've got to ask for more than 2 (because each physical CPUs has 2 threads). I'm rather ignorant on this topic, so I hope I explain it correctly. Note that it's specific to the given cluster which uses hyperthreading, so YMMV.